# Copy columns from Sheet1 to Sheet2 & remote duplicates using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I Copy/append all unique rows from SOURCE Spreadsheet to DESTINATION Spreadsheet.

- Spreadsheet #1 (SOURCE) - Contains ID's and Names. This sheet has duplicate rows. 500k+ rows (Access: View Only)
- Spreadsheet #2 (DESTINATION) - Contains only unique ID's with Names. (Access: Edit)

---

This script works, but it copies all (including duplicates).

```
function transferIDs() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('%'); //SOURCE
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('#'); //DESTINATION
  var ds = dss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ds.clear({contentsOnly: true});
  ds.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
}
```

---

#### Spreadsheet #1 SOURCE (contains duplicate rows)

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **ID** | **Name** |
| X123456 | John |
| Y112233 | Sarah |
| X998877 | Amanda |
| 012344 | Bob |
| X998877 | Amanda |

#### Spreadsheet #2 DESTINATION (Populated using GAS, no duplicates, Expected Outcome)

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **ID** | **Name** |
| X123456 | John |
| Y112233 | Sarah |
| X998877 | Amanda |
| 012344 | Bob |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  with [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

Change `SData` to

```
const SData = SRange.getValues().filter(
  (set => row => set.has(row[0]) ? false : set.add(row[0]))(new Set)
);
```

And modify the destination range:

```
ds.getRange(1,1,SData.length,SData[0].length).setValues(SData);
```

Comment: Wow, that's such a compact clean solution. Thank you so much! I noticed that your solution checks both columns instead of only the ID column. This results in the same ID being copied to the destination if the Name is different (or has a typo). Is there anyway to exclude the Name column b from being filtered?

Comment: @JamesReed68 Edited.

Comment: Flawless! Thank you very much! You really are TheMaster ;)